# Checking for alphanumeric characters and getting input from HTML form

Tags: html, perl, alphanumeric

I'm fairly new to programming in Perl and I have a couple of compilation issues I can't seem to resolve. My program gets input from this HTML form.

**Question:** Should my form use the post or get method?

```
<FORM action="./cgi-bin/Perl.pl" method="GET">
     <br>
     Full name: <br><input type="text" name="full_name" maxlength="20"><br>
     Username: <br><input type="text" name="user_name" maxlength="8"><br>
     Password: <br><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="15"><br>
     Confirm password: <br><input type="password" name="new_password" maxlength="15"><br>
```

I open a CSV file, write the value of user_name into an array and do a number of checks on the user's input.

**Problem #1:** I need to check that full_name, user_name, password, and new_password are all alphanumeric or a space but I keep getting multiple errors that look like:

```
Use of uninitialized value $full_name in string eq at Perl.pl line 33
```

I don't think I've used CGI correctly to get these values from the form. I also believe I'm not correctly checking for alphanumeric characters. How can I resolve this?

**Problem #2:** I need to redirect the user to a specific webpage if their passwords don't match and if the username is already taken. I used a meta redirect but it's not doing it successfully. How can I display a proper error page?

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use CGI qw(:standard);
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

#opening Members.csv for reading
my $file = '/home/2014/amosqu/public_html/cgi-bin/Members.csv';
open(my $csv, '<', $file)  || die "Could not open your file";

#getting these from HTML form
my $full_name = param('full_name');
my $user_name= param('user_name');
my $password = param('password');
my $new_password = param('new_password');

my @users = ();

#splitting each line of csv file
foreach (<$csv>) {
     chomp;
     my @fields = split (/\,/);
     push @users, $fields[1]; #put all usernames inside of array
}

close $csv;

#opening Members.csv for appending
open(my $fh, '>>', $file) || die "Could not open your file";

#SOURCE OF PROBLEM 1
#checking that all values are alphanumeric
if(($full_name && $user_name && $password && $new_password) eq /\A[[:alnum:]]+\z/) {
      #if passwords don't match, redirect to error page
      if($password ne $new_password){
         print qq(<html>\n);
         print qq(<head>\n);
         print qq(<title> Passwords don't match. </title> \n);
         print qq{<meta http-equiv="refresh"content="5;URL="http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~amosqu/registration.html">\n};
         print qq(</head>\n);
         print qq(<body>\n);
         print qq(<b><center> Passwords don't match </b></center>\n\n);
         print qq(</body>\n);
         print qq(</html>\n);
     }
      #if they do match, check that user name isn't in Members.csv
      else { 
          if(grep (/$user_name/, @users)) {
             print qq(<html>\n);
             print qq(<head>\n);
             print qq(<title> Sorry username already taken. </title>\n);
             print qq{<meta http-equiv="refresh"content="5;URL="http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~amosqu/registration.html">\n};
             print qq(</head>\n);
             print qq(<body>\n);
             print qq(<b><center> Username already taken. </b></center>\n\n);
             print qq(</body>\n);
             print qq(</html>\n);
        }
        #if it isn't already in Members.csv append values to the file
        else { 
             print $fh "$full_name, $user_name, $password \n";
       }
    }
}

close $fh;
```

Comment: Too many questions. You should first make sure you get the data right. As it seems that you don’t, why do you ask about *processing* the data now?

Answer (score 2):

This should get you going. There is a number of issues with your code that don't stop it from working, but current wisdom is not to use `CGI` at all so I will roll with you.

- Use `GET` unless you have a good reason to use `POST`
- The problem is here

  ```
  if(($full_name && $user_name && $password && $new_password) eq /\A[[:alnum:]]+\z/) {
  ```

  You are using a Boolean `&&` operation that combines the *truth* of the three variables, and checking whether that, as a string, is equal to the result of matching the contents of `$_` against that regular expression.

  You must check each of the variables individually, and use the *binding operator* `=~` to test them against a regex. It is also bad form to use the POSIX character classes. I suggest you use `grep`, like this

  ```
  my $mismatch = grep /[^A-Z0-9]/i, $full_name, $user_name, $password, $new_password;
  ```

  Now, `$mismatch` is *true* if any of the variables contain a non-alphanumeric character. (Strictly, it is set to the *number* of variables that have a a non-alphanumeric character, which is zero (false) if none of them do.)

  Then you can say

  ```
  if (not $mismatch) { ... }
  ```
- It looks like you just need an `else` that builds a separate page.

Comment: Thank you. I'm now properly checking if the inputs are alphanumeric but I continue to get the error "Use of uninitiliazed value $_". Is there something wrong with the way I'm getting these from the form?

Comment: You have misunderstood my solution. I cannot tell what is wrong unless you post your new code. I suggest that you should open a new question.