# Processing form data using CGI

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I'm programming in Perl and need to get data from the following HTML form:

```
<FORM action="./cgi-bin/Perl.pl" method="GET">
<br>
    Full name: <br><input type="text" name="full_name" maxlength="20"><br>
    Username: <br><input type="text" name="user_name" maxlength="8"><br>
    Password: <br><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="15"><br>
    Confirm password: <br><input type="password" name="new_password" maxlength="15"><br>
    <input type="submit" value ="Submit"><br><br>
</FORM>
```

**EDIT:** If i cannot use CGI.pm, will the following work?

```
local ($buffer, @pairs, $pair, $name, $value, %FORM);
    # Read in text
    $ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
    if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "GET") {
        read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
    }
    else {
    $buffer = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
    }

    # Split information into name/value pairs
    @pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
    foreach $pair (@pairs)
    {
       ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
        $value =~ tr/+/ /;
        $value =~ s/%(..)/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
        $FORM{$name} = $value;
    }
```

but every time I attempt to use these values I get the error:

```
 Use of unitilialized value
```

How can I properly use CGI to handle my form data?

**EDIT:** It's possible that my error lies elsewhere. This is my code. Could it be the way in which I'm using grep? Should I not be using the GET method?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use CGI qw(:standard);
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

#getting these from HTML form
my $full_name = param('full_name');
my $user_name= param('user_name');
my $password = param('password');
my $new_password = param('new_password');

#checking that inputs are alphanumeric or an underscore
my $mismatch = grep /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/i, $full_name, $user_name, $password, $new_password;

if($mismatch) {
    #error message if invalid input
    print qq(<html>\n);
    print qq(<head>\n);
    print qq(<title> Error: alphanumeric inputs only. </title>\n);
    print qq{<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL="http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~amosqu/registration.html">\n};
    print qq(</head>\n);
    print qq(<body>\n);
    print qq(<b><center> Inputs with alphanumeric characters only please. </b></center>\n\n);
    print qq(</body>\n);
    print qq(</html>\n);
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure those are the lines are giving you that error?

Comment: Note that CGI.pm will be removed from the next release of Perl. It is generally recommended to use a framework (such as Web::Simple, Dancer or Catalyst) that uses Plack. You can use the CGI runner for Plack if you need to deploy using CGI.

Comment: Thank you. I've now edited the question to include more code. It says specifically that the error is coming from the line where I've used grep?

Comment: CGI has funtions to output the headers and create the tags for you. Your HTML uses nested double quotes. Output the `$full_name` and others to the HTML for debugging.

Comment: **Do not** use the CGI.pm functions for generating HTML tags. The [manual for it says you shouldn't](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used)!

Comment: How do you expect someone to provide their full name without using any spaces? (Your regex appears to be backwards too - it forbids alphanumerics).

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you are getting though.

Comment: If you get error messages about uninitialized variables for `$full_name` etc., there is no point in considering further processing. But the code as such works in the sense that the form data gets passed to those variables. Even if a field is left blank, the data contain the corresponding variable, just an empty string as value (which is very different from being uninitialized). There is something in the overall setup that fails. Concentrate on testing first that you get the data passed OK, just echoing some of it. *Where* do you see the error messages?

Comment: You can test your script without going via the web-browser. Just `cd` into your `cgi-bin` directory and do `./Perl.pl full_name="Michael" username="MikeyBabe"`

Comment: You may also want to try changing the very first line to `<FORM action="/cgi-bin/Perl.pl" method="GET">` i.e. remove the period before the slash.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you for the suggestions. I've edited the original post to include some form processing that does not use CGI.pm.

Comment: @MarkSetchell — If the URL was wrong, it would 404.

Comment: @sofdelg — Rolling your own is worse that using CGI.pm. I listed a bunch of alternatives in the original comment. (Not that CGI.pm appears to be directly relevant to the problem you are experiencing).

Answer (score 1):

You have altered the regex that I suggested in my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244111), which was

```
grep /[^A-Z0-9]/i, $full_name, $user_name, $password, $new_password
```

You have changed it so that `$mismatch` is now set to the number of parameters that are *valid*, and the condition for an invalid set of arguments is now the awkward `$mismatch < 4`.

If your requirement has altered from alphanumeric to alphanumeric plus underscore, then you can restore the sense of the `grep` by writing

```
my $mismatch = grep /\W/, $full_name, $user_name, $password, $new_password
```

which will set `$mismatch` to a positive *true* value if *any* of the values contains a "non-word" character, which is alphanumeric plus underscore as you wanted.

However, the problem you are seeing

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//)
```

is because at least one of the parameters `$full_name`, `$user_name`, `$password`, or `$new_password` is undefined. You need to find out which one and why it is happening. Are you sure that all four query parameters `full_name`, `user_name`, `password`, and `new_password` are present in the query string you're getting back? Take a look at what the `query_string` method returns to see.

Answer (score -1):

Well, "use of initialized value" isn't an error, it's just a warning. More recent versions of Perl will tell you which variable is causing the problem.

Are you sure that it's the `grep` line that is generating the errors? Are you sure that you are filling in all of the form inputs when you're testing this?

The following suggestions, don't address your warning. But they are problems with your code.

The regex you are using for your `grep` seems broken. Your code says "set `$missing` to the number of variables that include nothing but alphanumeric characters". That will be set to four if you get four alphanumeric-only inputs. You then trigger the error page - which seems to be the inverse of what you want. Your regex also checks for zero or more alphanumeric characters. So it accepts the empty string. Is that what you want?

Also, your regex is too complicated. There's no need to include both `A-Z` and `a-z` if you're using `/i` to make the match case-insensitive. In fact your regex can be collapsed to `/^\w*$/i` (as `\w` means "alphanumeric characters plus an underscore").

Checking that inputs only contain alphanumeric characters is probably a bad idea as well. Most people's full names will include at least one space. And limiting passwords to just containing alphanumeric characters is a terrible idea.

When people point out that CGI is no longer recommended, that *doesn't* mean that you should go back to using Matt Wright's broken CGI parameter parser from twenty years ago. That code is just as broken as it always was. No-one should be using it. You should be looking at one of the modern Perl web development frameworks that are based on PSGI - something like Web::Simple, Dancer or Mojolicious. See [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) for details.